# Error FS0039: The namespace or module 'Xamarin' is not defined. (FS0039) in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-community

I created a multiplatform app in F# in Visual Studio Community edition for Mac.

[image]

Then I try to run the skeleton app in Debug mode. It instantly reports these namespace error

[image]

I expect Xamarin to be installed during VS installation. Why the namespace is missing and how can I fix it?